# Función para validar varios checkbox automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, html5, checkbox

Tengo el siguiente código donde una cajita muestra los `<checkbox>` que hacen falta seleccionar luego de presionar un botón. Sin embargo, necesito usar la función creada para validar los `<checkbox>` automáticamente. Lo estoy intentando con un `addEventListener()` pero no sé cómo llamarla para que me de respuesta automática.

```js
function chulos() {
    var suma=0;
    var checkboxes= document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if(checkboxes[i].checked != true){
        suma=suma+1;
      }
    }                 
    document.getElementById("cantChulos").innerHTML=suma;
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", chulos);
    console.log(suma);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Cantidad de Tareas Faltantes</p>
  <h3 id="cantChulos"> </h3>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Chulos Faltantes" onclick="chulos();"/>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Termina antes que acabe el tiempo</a>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept through metro Detroit
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Agradezco me colaboren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné así:

```
var checkboxes= document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
                                    window.onload = function chulos() {
                                        var suma=0;

                                        for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                                            checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", chulos);
                                            if(checkboxes[i].checked != true){
                                                suma=suma+1;
                                            }
                                        }                           
                                        document.getElementById("cantChulos").innerHTML=suma;

                                        console.log(suma);
                                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes solucionarlo así:

- Buscamos los `checkbox` a controlar y usando [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from) convertimos el resultado a un arreglo
- Con [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) les suscribimos la función `chulos` al evento `change`
- Con [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) obtenemos la cantidad que NO estan `checked`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function chulos() {
  // Verificamos cuales son los NO chequeados
  let suma = checkboxes.reduce((acc, check) => acc + !check.checked, 0);
  document.getElementById("cantChulos").innerHTML = suma;
}

// Buscamos los checkboxs
let checkboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input'));
// A cada uno le asignamos el listener
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', chulos));
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Cantidad de Tareas Faltantes</p>
  <h3 id="cantChulos"> </h3>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Chulos Faltantes" onclick="chulos();" />
  <div>
    <a href="#">Termina antes que acabe el tiempo</a>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept through metro Detroit
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo puedes tener la variable `checkbox` al inicio y fuera de la función `chulos()`:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
```

Luego debes agregar el listener a todos los checkbox, para eso puedes usar *destructuring* y `map()` de la siguiente forma:

```
[...checkboxes].map( e => e.addEventListener("click", chulos));
```

Y así queda el código funcionando:

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
[...checkboxes].map( e => e.addEventListener("click", chulos));

function chulos() {
    var suma=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
      if(checkboxes[i].checked != true)
        suma=suma+1;          
    document.getElementById("cantChulos").innerHTML=suma;
    console.log(suma);
}

chulos();
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Cantidad de Tareas Faltantes</p>
  <h3 id="cantChulos"> </h3>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Chulos Faltantes" onclick="chulos();"/>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Termina antes que acabe el tiempo</a>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept through metro Detroit
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacerlo con un evento `onchange` con la clase como selector puede ser `change` o `clic` aplicara para los todos inputs con la clase `form-check-input`

Ejemplo:

```
var suma=0;
$(document).on('change','.form-check-input', function(){
   if((this).is(':checked')){
        suma=suma+1;
   }
});
console.log(suma);
```

Comment: Espera, ella no especifico que podía usar jquery.

Comment: Exacto, no puedo hacer uso de JQuery. Gracias